# Почему медиа запросы не работают?

Tags: css, media-queries

Медиа запросы не работают:

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Стили в правильном порядке.

```css
    .contact {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .contact {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Как Вы проверяете, медиа запрос?

Comment: Все понял, консолью почему-то не работает